# ¿Como puedo hacer para que mi gráfica imprima la cantidad de reporte que se hacen por día?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

Estoy tratando de crear una gráfica de barra que me muestre cuántos reportes se hacen por día.

La gráfica me lo muestra pero no sé cómo puedo hacer que sumen las columnas que tienen la misma fecha y la muestre.

Este es mi tabla de la base de datos que quiero sacar los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es donde de imprime la gráfica

```
<h1>Gráfica creada con PHP</h1>
        <a href="https://parzibyte.me/blog">By Parzibyte</a>
        <canvas id="grafica"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>public/js/chartjs.js"></script>
```

el js:

```
(async () => {
// Llamar a nuestra API. Puedes usar cualquier librería para la llamada, yo uso fetch, que viene nativamente en JS
const respuestaRaw = await fetch("http://localhost/bavproyecto/main/GraficaBarra");
// Decodificar como JSON
const respuesta = await respuestaRaw.json();
// Ahora ya tenemos las etiquetas y datos dentro de "respuesta"
// Obtener una referencia al elemento canvas del DOM
const $grafica = document.querySelector("#grafica");
const etiquetas = respuesta.etiquetas; // <- Aquí estamos pasando el valor traído usando AJAX
// Podemos tener varios conjuntos de datos. Comencemos con uno
const datosVentas2020 = {
    label: "Ventas por mes",
    // Pasar los datos igualmente desde PHP
    data: respuesta.datos, // <- Aquí estamos pasando el valor traído usando AJAX
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', // Color de fondo
    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', // Color del borde
    borderWidth: 1, // Ancho del borde
};
new Chart($grafica, {
    type: 'bar', // Tipo de gráfica
    data: {
        labels: etiquetas,
        datasets: [
            datosVentas2020,
            // Aquí más datos...
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
        },
    }
});
})();
```

y la funcion de php

```
function GraficaBarra(){

        $grafi = $this->model->graficoM();

        foreach ($grafi as $value) {

        // Valores con PHP. Estos podrían venir de una base de datos o de cualquier lugar del servidor
        $etiquetas = [$value->fecha];
        $datosVentas = [$value->id];
        }
        // Ahora las imprimimos como JSON para pasarlas a AJAX, pero las agrupamos
        $respuesta = [
            "etiquetas" => $etiquetas,
            "datos" => $datosVentas,
        ];
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
```

Cuya función llama el modelo que contiene esto:

```
 function graficoM(){
       $itemsRepor = [];
        $resultadoRepor = $this->db->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM reporte");
        $resultadoRepor->execute();
        $itemsRepor  = $resultadoRepor->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
        return $itemsRepor;
    }
```

Entonces lo que yo quiero es saber cómo hago  para que me imprima la cantidad de reporte hecho por día.

Y también no sé porque me imprime solo un resultado ya que debería de imprimir varios.

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes que realizar los siguientes cambios:

- Necesitas obtener los datos **agrupados por fecha y contarlos**. Así por ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT 
  fecha,
  COUNT(id) AS total 
FROM reporte 
GROUP BY fecha
```

- Finalmente, necesitas modificar como armar el JSON de respuesta

```php
$grafi = $this->model->graficoM();
$etiquetas = []; // Creamos los arreglos
$datos = [];
foreach ($grafi as $value) {
    $etiquetas[] = $value->fecha; // Agregamos al arreglo
    $datos[] = $value->total;
}
$respuesta = [
  "etiquetas" => $etiquetas,
  "datos" => $datos,
];
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Comment: A ok muchas gracias :)